# Asymptotic Growth of Run Time of function with three nested for loops

Tags: algorithm, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I have pseudo code for a function (below).
 I understand that if each of `i`, `j` and `k` were `1` then worst case run time would be `O(n^3)`. I am struggling to understand the impact of `n/2` though - if any - on run time. Any guidance would be great.

```
for i=n/2; i < n; increase i by 1
    for j=1; j < n/2; increase j by 1
        for k = 1; k < n; increase k by k*2
            Execute a Statement
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding is not correct

`k` is increased by `k*2` which leads to logarithmic time, the complexity is actually `O(n^2 * log n)`

The `O(n/2) = O(n)`, therefore the `n/2` does not have any impact on asymptotic growth.

---

If you are not sure, the general approach is to count it as precise as possible and then remove the constants.

`for i` will be execute `n/2` times, the `for j` also `n/2` times and `k` will be executed `log n` times.

`n/2 * n/2 * log n = (n^2/4) * log n`. You can remove constants, so `O(n^2 * log)`

Answer (score 0):

The worst case time complexity is not `O(N^3)`

Check the innermost for loop. `K` increases by `K * 2`
That means, the innermost for loop will take `O(lgN)` time

Other two outer loops would take `O(N)` time each and `N/2` would not have any effect on the asymptotic growth of run time.

So, the overall time complexity would be `O(N^2 * lgN)`